# How to reinitialize a Spring Bean which is @Document?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring Bean, which is annotated by `@Document`, So I create `@Bean` for this class, to make able to get this class by `@Autowired`. But now I want to change the content of this Bean, so after 5 seconds it will automatically change the content of this bean (For example if something changes in Collection, `@Autowired` class will get these changes automatically). How can I do that? 
Class, which I have as a `@Bean`:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Document(collection = CollectionNames.CONFIG_DATA)
public class ConfigData {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Profiles profiles;
    private EmailConfig emailConfig;
    private ScheduledConfig scheduledConfig;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public static class EmailConfig {
        private String email;
        private String password;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public static class ScheduledConfig {
        private Long time;
        private TimeUnit timeUnit;

        public long convertToMilliseconds(long value, TimeUnit unit) {
            return switch (unit) {
                case HOURS -> java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(value);
                case MINUTES -> java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(value);
                case SECONDS -> java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(value);
            };
        }

        public enum TimeUnit {
            HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS
        }
    }
}
```

Where I create `@Bean` to this class:

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigDataService configDataService;
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ConfigData configData() {
        return configDataService.getConfigDataByProfile(Profiles.valueOf(environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)));
    }
}
```

I try many ways, I try by deleting Bean with `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` by using the method `destroySingleton` and then `registerSingleton` but it causes Error messages.

I also add scheduler to update ConfigData, but it's not working:

```java
@Service
public class TestOne {
    @Autowired
    private MongoConfig mongoConfig;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigData configData;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void test() {
        ConfigData configData1 = mongoConfig.configData();
        configData.setScheduledConfig(configData1.getScheduledConfig());
    }
}
```

Comment: All the clients of this bean have references to the same instance, so why don't you just modify the state of the bean?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Call a setter on the bean. e.g `myAutowiredConfigDataInstance.setScheduledConfig(newScheduledConfig)`

Comment: But it will work only in Java class, where I will change it, so I want to adjust in all classes, where it's ```@Autowired```, understand?

Comment: All of those auto wired references point to the same bean. Spring beans are (by default) singletons. So when you change a field, all the other clients of that bean will see it.

Comment: Okay, where can I change the bean's state, which class? In the same ```MongoConfig```? Or do I need to make another class?

Comment: You say you want some code which runs every 5 minutes and loads state from the DB? Make a bean with an @Scheduled method and do it there.

Comment: Please edit your question with clarifications, code is comments is unreadable.

Comment: I've posted in answers

Comment: Time to do some debugging. Is that method getting called? Is it getting different values from the DB? How can you tell that your configData bean isn't being updated?

Comment: I have another scheduler, which calls ConfigData and It's not modify, It's only calls ```CofnigData``` by ```@Autowired```

Comment: When I call ```mongoConfig.configData()```, it doesn't get the last DB updates...

Comment: Use the configDataService directly.

Comment: Ah now it works, when I use directly ```ConfigDataService```, thank you!

Comment: I think `MongoConfig.configdata()`, because it is in a @Config class with a @Bean annotation is a proxy which always returns the same instance.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to change the content of the ConfigData's Bean, as suggested, you could make use of a Prototype Bean, here's an [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton) giving some context.

However, if changing the content of the  ConfigData's Bean isn't a problem, I think you'll still need to implement some kind of [Observer](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer) to notify the ConfigData's dependents, unless, of course, the values are only relevant in some kind of method invocation.

Comment: Well, I want to change the content of the ConfigData's Bean without recompilation.
So what I mean: ConfigData gets data from the database while compiling, after some changes into the database, I want maybe once in 5 minutes or maybe with some API request to change ConfigData with the last database changes.

Comment: Right, but my suggestion didn't imply any recompilation, either way, since you didn't give much detail about your scenario's limitation, I've just wanted to give you more options! The second part of my suggestion, however, would suffice for your scenario. I don't get the down vote, tho.